# Compressing Picked Image Size Xamarin before Uploading to cloud

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin app where user's can pick Images using the Xamarin Essentials plugin. My issue now is finding away to shrink the image size using the image full path, before it's loaded to the cloud.

The Code

```
// Pick Image
    private async Task PickImages()
    {
        if (ImageCollection.Count >= 10)
        {
            ToastMessageLong("Cannot Select More then 10 Images.");
            return;
        }
        ImageLink image = new();
        try
        {
            FileResult result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Pick an Image"
            });

            if (result == null) return;

            image.PostImages = result.FullPath;
            ImageCollection.Add(image);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", x.Message);
        }
    }


    private async Task UploadImagesToCloud()
    {
        if (ImageCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            List<ImageLink> imageLinks = new();
            foreach (ImageLink img in ImageCollection)
            {
                // Need to Compress Image before adding to cloud..

                ImageLink link = await CloudService.CS.UploadPostImage(img.PostImages);
                imageLinks.Add(link);
            }
            P.Images = imageLinks;
        }
    }
```

Comment: shrink how?  By reducing the width and height of the image?  Or by saving at a higher compression level?  Both approaches have been discussed multiple times.

Comment: Reduce the image size e.g from 8mb to 220 kb.

Comment: I've already tried some examples already and get thrown an not supported on platform exception.

Comment: as I explained above, there are two common methods used to decrease image size - which do you want to use?

Comment: https://schwabencode.com/blog/2019/06/11/Resize-Image-NET-Core

Answer (score 0):

You could resize the image size befor uploading it to cloud.Here is one method for resizing the image:

```
#if __IOS__
    public static byte[] ResizeImageIOS(byte[] imageData, float width, float height)
    {
        UIImage originalImage = ImageFromByteArray(imageData);
        UIImageOrientation orientation = originalImage.Orientation;

        //create a 24bit RGB image
        using (CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero,
                                             (int)width, (int)height, 8,
                                             4 * (int)width, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(),
                                             CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
        {

            RectangleF imageRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);

            // draw the image
            context.DrawImage(imageRect, originalImage.CGImage);

            UIKit.UIImage resizedImage = UIKit.UIImage.FromImage(context.ToImage(), 0, orientation);

            // save the image as a jpeg
            return resizedImage.AsJPEG().ToArray();
        }
    }


#if __ANDROID__
    
    public static byte[] ResizeImageAndroid (byte[] imageData, float width, float height)
    {
        // Load the bitmap
        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)width, (int)height, false);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            resizedImage.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
            return ms.ToArray ();
        }
    }
```

you could refer to [ImageResizer](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/XamFormsImageResize/XamFormsImageResize/ImageResizer.cs#L44)

Comment: thanks I was given another solution using SkiaSharp.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I was Given using SkiaSharp.

```
    public static string CreateThumbnail(string Path, string fileName)
    {
        var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(Path);
        int h = bitmap.Height;
        int w = bitmap.Width;
        int newWidth = w;
        int newHeight = h;
        //resize algorythm
        if (h > 1080 || w > 1080)
        {
            int rectHeight = 1080;
            int rectWidth = 1080;

            //aspect ratio calculation
            float W = w;
            float H = h;
            float aspect = W / H;

            //new dimensions by aspect ratio
            newWidth = (int)(rectWidth * aspect);
            newHeight = (int)(newWidth / aspect);

            //if one of the two dimensions exceed the box dimensions
            if (newWidth > rectWidth || newHeight > rectHeight)
            {
                //depending on which of the two exceeds the box dimensions set it as the box dimension and calculate the other one based on the aspect ratio
                if (newWidth > newHeight)
                {
                    newWidth = rectWidth;
                    newHeight = (int)(newWidth / aspect);
                }
                else
                {
                    newHeight = rectHeight;
                    newWidth = (int)(newHeight * aspect);
                }
            }
        }

        var resizedImage = bitmap.Resize(new SKImageInfo(newWidth, newHeight), SKBitmapResizeMethod.Lanczos3);
        var image = resizedImage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, 80);
        var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        string finalPath = filepath;
        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
            image.SaveTo(stream);
        return finalPath;
    }
```